# Can it be better to create a cursor over data copied to a table variable instead of the actual table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I've had some bad experiences with cursors causing deadlocks.  I have been trying to eliminate cursors wherever possible.  When they are unavoidable, I try minimize the amount of work done while the cursor is open.

Is it ever better to copy the data to a table variable, and build a cursor over the table variable?

I know the answer will likely depend on the size of the data set.  At them moment, I am concerned with a very small, data set (a handlefull of records), that is rarely updated.  On occasion I will still have create complex loops over large data sets.

Is there any benefit to copying to table variables, or am I over-complicating things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the cursor as `STATIC` when you declare it, SQL Server will make a temporary copy of the data for you automatically.

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx):

> STATIC
>
> Defines a cursor that makes a temporary copy of the data to be used
>   by the cursor. All requests to the
>   cursor are answered from this
>   temporary table in tempdb; therefore,
>   modifications made to base tables are
>   not reflected in the data returned by
>   fetches made to this cursor, and this
>   cursor does not allow modifications.

Comment: I was my understanding that cursors can still create locking problems on tempdb.  I was also under the impression that table variables are much faster than temporary tables.

Comment: Table variables are not always faster than temporary tables. Your best bet is probably to test both approaches and see which works better in your specific case.